# How to send the Id of this anchor as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Edit: Sorry guys, I got the issue, Misspelled class name :(** 
 
Hey, I got a quick question for your guys here. I have some anchor tags each of them points to a url of a certain user. The link id is the username. All the links share a css class (.userset). When a user clicks the link I need to issue an Ajax request -using jQuery.ajax method- to a server resource passing in the id of the link. Here's how my code looks like: 
 
**JS**

```
 $(".columnist_set .img").click(function() {

        alert("this.id =" + this.id);
        var x = track(this.id);
});
```

This doesn't seem to work for me! this.id is always undefined. 
Yeah, I'm suer I'm missing something, so what am I missing dear SO Gus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, I misspelled the class name so the returned wrapped set of my selector is undefined. Thanks for your help all though.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** (I was on the wrong track because of some probably incorrect assumptions)

Try the following:

```
$(".columnist_set .img").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert("id =" + id);
        var x = track(id);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. It's just not working for me. Are you sure this will give me the id of the anchor?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(".userset").click(function() {
   var x = track($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your request i can feel some confusion.

Your request says:

> I have some anchor tags
>   each of them points to a url of a
>   certain user.

With this sentence you mean you have many `<a>` in your code, with the `href` attribute pointing to some user-driven path.

> The link id is the username. All the links share a css
>   class (.userset).

More info, why not. Your tag now should look in my mind like `<a class=".userset" id="myUserName" href="./some/url">content</a>`

> When a user clicks
>   the link I need to issue an Ajax
>   request -using jQuery.ajax method- to
>   a server resource passing in the id of
>   the link

Let's add the click event:

```
   //all the anchor tags with "userset" class
   $('a.userset').click(
      function(){
          //doing the ajax call
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: $(this).attr("href"),      //picking the href url from the <a> tag
              data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"),    //sanitize if it's a free-inputed-string
              success:
                function(result) {
                    alert("I AM THE MAN! Data returned: " + result);
                }
              }
          );
      }
   );
```

With that being said, i can't really understand what your javascript code (with references to **.img class**?) is referring to.

Hope my answer helped a bit though.